# Airflow dag lagging a month

Tags: python, cron, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Based on research and how my DAG is behaving, if I have a dag setup like this:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 6, 25),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=100),
    'provide_context': True
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=True,
    schedule_interval='0 6 25 * *'
)
```

This will run at 6 am on the 25th of each month. For example, given the above configuration, if today is 8/25 and I create this DAG today, it will run 6/25 and 7/25 because catchup = True. However, the 6/25 and 7/25 DAG runs are ***executed*** on 7/25 and 8/25, respectively.

I understand this is because the DAG executes at the end of the period, but I find it incredibly misleading. I want the execution date for the 8/25 run to show as 8/25, not 7/25 - is there a way to override this? Perhaps with `{{ next_ds }}` somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing between logical run date and the data interval window it's processing.

As you figured out DAGs are schedueled at the end of the interval. This means that the run of `2021-06-25` with a monthly interval will be executed on `2021-07-25`. This is something you can not control and can not change. This is just as Airflow works. I'm putting a side note here as [AIP-39 Richer scheduler_interval](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval) will change it in the future.

However, all of the above doesn't mean that you can't control over what dates this run actually process. On that you have full control. You can parse records on any window - yesterday data, last week data, last month data - anything you want. You decide on that. As you mentioned the key to understand how to "play" with these windows with [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html) `{{ ds }}, {{ next_ds }}, {{ prev_ds }}` etc... you can also write your own custom macros if needed.
All that is left is just to understand what each value of this macros means in a specific run so you can choose which macros to use in your code. Say that your code is executing a SQL: `SELECT val FROM table WHERE date IS BETWEEN x AND Y`. In this SQL `x` & `Y` will be replaced by macros.

By your setup the values will be:

| execution_date | will run on | prev_ds | ds | next_ds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-25 | 2021-07-25 | None | 2021-06-25 | 2021-07-25 |
| 2021-07-25 | 2021-08-25 | 2021-06-25 | 2021-07-25 | 2021-08-25 |
| 2021-08-25 | 2021-09-25 | 2021-07-25 | 2021-08-25 | 2021-09-25 |
| 2021-09-25 | 2021-10-25 | 2021-08-25 | 2021-09-25 | 2021-10-25 |

Comment: Thanks for this. Now that I understand this fully, updating my jobs should be easy enough. The Confluence link you sent is also really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try set the 'start_date' to an earlier date, instead of the exact 6/25. If the start date is 6/20, the first run will be executed on 6/25.